# Base64 Url issue on chrome and Edge

Tags: html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I want to open images on click of anchor tag. I am using below code which is working fine in Firefox but not working on Chrome and Edge Error in Console ""Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: ". I have tried adding ==,= at the end of base64 string but it did not worked. Thanks in advance.

```
           <a href="data:image/png;base64, '.$b64image.'"  target="_blank">View</a>
```

I Have tried

```
         <a href="data:image/png;base64, '.$b64image.'=="  target="_blank">View</a>
         <a href="data:image/png;base64, '.$b64image.'="  target="_blank">View</a>
```

Comment: Describe "not working". What happens? Are there any errors in the console. Give as much information as you can.

Comment: "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: " this error in console of chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a chrome security restriction. You can bypass it in the following way.

```
function debugBase64(base64URL){
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}
```

Call this function on click of the link using an event listener.

[Source](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/682/what-does-the-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url-javascript-exception-means-in-google-chrome)